# Determine Application State in Presentation Layer or Business Layer

Tags: java, rest, ejb, hateoas

I’m looking for some guidance on whether the presentation layer or business layer of an application should be responsible for determining the application state and what actions should be presented in the response when interacting with a resource.

The project I’m working on is a Java EE based application with JAX-RS for the REST based presentation layer, stateless EJBs for the business layer, and JPA for the persistence layer, although I will add other types of presentation layer in the future such as a JSF based web app, and a Rich Client.

As a very simple example the resource is a bank account and if the balance is £100 then the actions could be “deposit”, “withdraw”, “transfer” or “close”, however if the balance is -£25 then the only available action would be “deposit”. From the viewpoint of the REST interface, if a GET request fetches an account resource the response would include HATEOAS links for each of the available actions depending upon the balance.

**My first question** using this example is whether the presentation layer should check the balance returned by the business layer and then decide which HATEOAS links should be included in the response or alternatively should the business layer return a list of available actions for a given resource to the presentation layer which would then be converted to HATEOAS links.

As this is essentially business logic, the business layer seems like to most appropriate place, but this then raises **the second question** as to how the list of available actions should be made available to the presentation layer.

**My third question** is whether there is a better way to achieve the same result. I’m somewhat surprised that a Google search hasn’t revealed anyone trying to solve the same problem. I’ve looked at using rich domain objects rather than anaemic domain objects, but this seems to go against the Java EE/EJB/JPA way of doing things.

Irrespective of whether this is done in the presentation layer or business layer, the business layer will still check that the action is valid when the respective action (“deposit”, “withdraw”, “transfer”, “close”) is called.

The actual business logic in my project is more complex but wanted to provide a simple example for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I would suggest you do this at your business layer and provide the list of allowed actions to the presentation layer. This will encapsulate your business logic and also allow to reuse the same logic if you need to provide it for any other clients in future. From scaling, it is easier to scale if you push these logic to presentation but UI technologies are changing so rapidly and by looking at the trend companies are more frequently changing the UI stack than services.